# Original Paper on Slow Neutron Capture by Fermi?

Tags: nuclear-physics, specific-reference

I was wondering what the title of his original publication on Neutron capture was. I've found his Nobel lecture but I want to read his initial publication. A title would be most appreciated. 
It's currently hard to find it since searching his name brings up a lot autobiographical material, telescopes, Stanford publication archives, you name it. A link to the original wins you a big e-hug =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the very first, but an early paper is [Artificial Radioactivity Produced by Neutron Bombardment, Fermi et al., Proc. Roy. Soc. London A **146**, 483–500 (1934)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2935604). First footnote on the first page refers to about eight "preliminary results announced in short communications," mostly with Fermi as an author.

Comment: e-hug commencing